# ListBox in wp7 doesn't work for me

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm trying to present a listview in wp7 and for some reason it doesn't seem to work

my xaml

```
            <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="list">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Stretch="None"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

my c# code

```
    public class list
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imageSource { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<list> dataSources = new List<list>();
        dataSources.Add(new list() { title = "Shacharit", imageSource = "Images/shacharit.png" });
        dataSources.Add(new list() { title = "Mincha", imageSource = "Images/mincha.png" });
        dataSources.Add(new list() { title = "Arvit", imageSource = "Images/arvit.png" });
        dataSources.Add(new list() { title = "Birkat HaMazon", imageSource = "Images/shacharit.png" });
        list.ItemsSource = dataSources;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it doesn't seem to work means what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below, change the bindings of image and text block to bind to the strings you have declared at present you are trying to bind to ImageURI and Text and they don't exist in any of your code.

```
           <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="list" Da>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <Image Source="{Binding imageSource }" Stretch="None"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Great, glad to help. Can you accept mine and Zombiesheeps answer then. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To Clarify Jon D's answer, you are creating data objects with attributes of "imagePath" and "title" in your code behind

```
new list() { title = "Shacharit", imageSource = "Images/shacharit.png" };
```

but trying to bing to properties called "ImageUri" and "Text".

In your output window in VS you should see these binding errors show up.

The following 2 lines (where you are doinng the binding in the XAML) should fix things up for you...

```
<Image Source="{Binding imageSource }" Stretch="None"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
```